# css Toggle switch does not change checkbox value/state

Tags: css, angular, toggleswitch

I am trying to create an toggle a switch.
the tempate I used is from:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

every things works fine but the checked or value of the (hidden) checkbox does not change. I need this value for my angular(4) binding

How can you acchieve this?

Comment: setting checked to true of false does not work (it is not even valid), you can only set checked or remove it. but after toggling, the checkbox value state does not change

Comment: Add some code so that we can see whats the problem

Comment: @mateusz The problem is described in the text. if is not clear for you please place a comment and I will provide you the requested information. Just downvoting isn't helping anyone.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using binding.

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="checkbx"
(change)="checkbx = !checkbx" formControlName="name">

In Ts file:
private checkbx: boolean = true;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [this.checkbx, Validators.required ],
    });
}

addvalue(checkbx: boolean){
  console.log(this.heroForm.value)
}
```

[check this live link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdbc8e?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: How can I use this whitout a form the toggleswich is a seperate component which will be used troughout the application

Comment: Thank you Prasanth. I have reviewed your solution and I am missing the checked value on the checkbox itself.