# How to bind the checkbox values in angular4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

Can you please share the code how to bind the checkbox value in angular? once i bind the check box value its shows only true or false. How to bind the value in angular4?

Comment: a check box should only be true (checked) or false (not checked)

Comment: How to bind the multiple checked values in angular?

Comment: if you follow the angular tutorial, im pretty sure it tells you how to do basic tasks like data binding

Comment: Use ngModel to bind your data to template'

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027915/css-toggle-switch-does-not-change-checkbox-value-state/49028627#49028627), guess this is what you expecting

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

in template (.html)

```
<input type="checkbox" [value]="item.Id" (change)="changerRoles($event)">  
 //you can bind a value using [value]
```

in component.ts

```
changerRoles(event) {

console.log(event.target.checked)  // from event.target.checked you can get weather checkbox is checked or not
console.log(event.target.value)  // from event.target.value you can get the binded value

}
```